# Firefox: Cannot find the full-screen-api.approval-required setting

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

Before Firefox 43, there was a setting called full-screen-api.approval-required in the about:config section to turn off the full screen warning pop up. I cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Firefox 43+ doesn’t offer the full-screen-api.approval-required preference, it has been removed. But you can still disable the message in version 43 buy changing the value of the **full-screen-api.warning.timeout** preference in **about:config** to **0**.